# System-level Proxy switcher using Java

Tags: java, winapi, networking, proxy

Can we use Java (included JNA) to change Windows proxy settings (System level, not just for JVM) on the fly. I found some code snippets for C# where they are using InternetSetOption() API provided by wininte.dll. I've tried but it does not work also. All I want is to change IE and Chrome proxy settings by running a JAR file (desktop app) without restarting the browser.

Thank you so much!